# ParentForm class usage

Tags: c#, winforms

I am just wondering why couldn't I use the Forms.ParentForm class for assigning a value to a ParentForm member from a Child Form.
Like:

```
ParentForm.database.Remove(this.userAuth.Key);
ParentForm.database.Add(this.userAuth.Key, newValue);
```

Thanks for any recommendation!

Answer (score 2):

The [ParentForm property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.parentform(v=vs.110).aspx) is just of type `Form`... you can't access anything from your *specific* parent Form without casting it to that type first.

Assuming `database` is accessible and your parent Form is named "YourParentForm":

```
((YourParentForm)ParentForm).database.Remove(this.userAuth.Key);
```

Alternatively, you might consider passing the instance of the database to the child when you instantiate the child Form, via the constructor for instance, instead.

```
private SomeDatabaseType database;

public YourChildForm(SomeDatabaseType database)
{
    this.database = database;
}
```

Comment: As Grant says, this would work, but accessing a variable of the parent form directly from the child form is not the most convenient way of doing this. If you need to access the database in the child form, you should pass the instance of the database to the child form.

Comment: As I am trying to get along, I want to test my Solution. In the same topic a new question aroses, because the new form simply doesn't opens. I use the code: `childForm = new ChildForm(userData); childForm.Activate();` from **ParentForm** prospective. But the build error disappears, so thanks!

Comment: @Grant Winney It's allright! The old forms I want to hide, while the new is open.

Answer (score 0):

ParentForm return a Form object, that doesn't have a "database" property.
Just cast returned value to your specific type

```
MyFormType parent = (MyFormType)ParentForm;
parent.database.Remove(this.userAuth.Key);
parent.database.Add(this.userAuth.Key, newValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Forms.ParentForm` like this, just as long as you (1) make `database` either internal (if the forms are in the same project) or `public` and (2) cast `ParentForm` to its real type.

You shouldn't do this though. You are tightly coupling the form to a specific parent form if you do. This will make writing tests harder and will make it harder to change the code later if you need the form to belong to a different parent (eg, re-use it elsewhere). The better approach is to inject a reference to `database` into the form via its constructor.